# stm32 Lora UART communication

Tags: stm32, uart, lora

I have 2 lora module. I want to use one of them as receiver and the other one as transmitter. I can do this with 2 Arduino uno but I want to use one STM32 board as transmitter and Arduino uno board for receiver.
I am using e byte lora module, E32433T20D.

I set the receiver Lora paramater like this :
`{0x00, 0x01 ,0x1A ,0x17 ,0xC0} ;`

Here is my Arduino transmitter code.

```
#define PIN_SERIAL1_TX (0u)
#define PIN_SERIAL1_RX (1u)

#define M0 14
#define M1 15
void setup() {
  pinMode(M0, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(M1, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(M0, LOW);
  digitalWrite(M1, LOW);
  Serial1.begin(9600);   // UART initialize I am using RP2040 with Arduino code
}
void loop() {
    Serial1.write((byte)0x00); //Receiver Adress
    Serial1.write(0x01);       //Receiver Adress                                                 
    Serial1.write(0x17);       //Receiver channel =0x17=23    (410M+23=433 MHz)
    Serial1.println("123");
    delay(500);
}
```

This code can transmit "123" without any problem. When I try this on C language ;

```
#include "main.h"
UART_HandleTypeDef huart1;
UART_HandleTypeDef huart2;

void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void);  //debug
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void);  //Lora

/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */
uint16_t readValue;
uint8_t charToTransmit[1];

/* USER CODE END 0 */

int main(void)
{

  HAL_Init();

  SystemClock_Config();

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();  //DEBUG
  MX_USART1_UART_Init();
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB,GPIO_PIN_5,0); //M0
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC,GPIO_PIN_7,0); //M1
  HAL_Delay(100);
  uint8_t config[]=  {0x00,0x01,0x1A,0X17,0XC0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
        charToTransmit[0] = 1 ;
        HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1,config,sizeof(config),0);
        HAL_Delay(500);
        HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1,charToTransmit,1,100);
        HAL_Delay(500);
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

// There are HAL library initialize over here
```

This code is not transmitting or my receiver is not receive I don't know but I can't see "1" on my receiver side. Since I am beginner of C, is my UART protocol wrong or something ?

Here is my receiver program, I wrote it from arduino IDE too.

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#define PIN_SERIAL1_TX (0u)
#define PIN_SERIAL1_RX (1u)
#define M0 14
#define M1 15
char rc;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial1.begin(9600);
  pinMode(M0, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(M1, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(M0, LOW);
  digitalWrite(M1, LOW);
}
void loop() {
    while (Serial1.available()) {
      rc=Serial1.read();
      Serial.print(rc);   
    }
  }
```

Comment: The ASCII code for "1" is 0x31, but you're sending 0x01.  Where is the `charToTransmit` array declared?  How do you initialize the UART?  It would be helpful if you can post a "complete" program

Comment: it would make more sense to post a working Arduino transmit program and the non-working STM32 transmit program

Comment: @OskarSkog sorry for late update, I am going to try with ASCII code instead of hexadecimal. I posted complete program Arduino and cubemx.

Comment: @jsotola sorry for late update I have posted  full code now.

Comment: Guys I manage to get the data, I wrote these hexadecimal values in decimal format. That's it. I think my hexadecimal format is wrong, if I correct it, I can send it even with hexadecimal format.

Comment: the working Arduino code is sending different bytes from the non-working code ... why did you write different code?

Comment: it send same I guess. Arduino is not sending these "0X17,0XC0" . I removed these on stm32's code too. Nothing change.